# How to add vertical scroll in Phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova

I would like to add vertical scroll in Phonegap app. The app is able to move left and right.. but not up and down.. Need some guidance on how to do it.. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on how your app is set up there are a few options out there.

1) If you don't need a fixed header ( very rare but does happen ) you can use a normal css approach, phonegap is just a webview wrapped as a native app, so most things in a browser will work here.

2) if you need a fixed header and footer I suggest [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4).

iOS 5 gave us `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`, which works in mobile safari, BUT since a webview is mobile safari's little brother you aren't given all of the awesomeness that regular safari has.

Answer (score 0):

all containers, which are higher than 100% viewport con carry the CSS: overflow: auto or overflow: scroll.

important is, that the container (i think a div) is set to height: 100%.

this is a idea for solving with CSS.