# How to prevent keyboard push up webview at iOS app using phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, webview, keyboard

When an input field at bottom of the screen has focus, the keyboard pushes up my webview and the upper part of the page is not visible anymore.

I want to prevent the keyboard pushing up the webview.

Anyone has an idea ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

On focus, set **window.scrollTo(0,0);** This prevents keyboard from pushing up webview completely

```
$('input').on('focus', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();
    window.scrollTo(0,0); //the second 0 marks the Y scroll pos. Setting this to i.e. 100 will push the screen up by 100px. 
});
```

If you **don't want to set a static value** for your Y scroll position, feel free to use this [short plugin I've written that automatically aligns the keyboard underneath the input field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13808307/1262619). It's not perfect, but it does the job. Just call this on focus as shown above:

```
setKeyboardPos(e.target.id);
```

Comment: It doesn't work on my iPad2/iOS6. a "setTimeout(function() { windows.scrollTo(0, 0);}, 0)" can fix it, but sometimes you can still see a litter jitter animation.

Comment: I think it should be window not windows

Answer (score 14):

Solved this issue using *driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard* (https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard)

First install keyboard plugin:

```
cordova plugin add com.ionic.keyboard
```

Now you can **I)** either disable native keyboard scrolling:

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
```

or **II)** listen on `native.keyboardshow` event in `deviceready` and scroll back to top when keyboard shows:

```
window.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow', keyboardShowHandler);

function keyboardShowHandler(e){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);
    }, 0);
}
```

I used the II) approach because I liked the animated scrolling in my case. If you don't want to go with the animation replace the corresponding line with `window.scrollTo(0, 0);`. But I'm afraid that in that case you will again have to deal with this "litter jitter animation" *Imskull* wrote about.

Comment: if using WKWebView(iOS), it doesn't allow cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true); , seems like i will try II) and see what happens.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and none of the solutions above helped me 
but I found a simple way to go past it.

In the platform/android folder open the manifest.xml and in the main activity tag replace the android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" attribute with android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

now the keyboard will overlay your content.

I hope it will help someone.

Comment: Thanks you saved me a lot of time.

Comment: The question is for iOS, not Android, how is this answer getting upvotes?

Answer (score 4):

I LITERALLY WENT THROUGH 100 answers before I had to find answer myself. so here it is how to disable scroll of UI on IOS.
simply when cordova is loading, add this.
Please install:

```
cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard --save
```

and then do `cordova prepare` to load this new plugin in your www folder.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(e){
    window.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow', function () {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
        });
});
```

And that's it. Please let me know if this was helpful. I will be glad to answer more.

Comment: This plugin is deprecated - use https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard

Comment: Adding plugin "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard", solved my issue temporarily for iOS 13 as well

Comment: Adding "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard", solved my issue for iOS 15, and I used it in a plain Cordova project (without Ionic).  Just adding the plugin solved the problem, I didn't need to call disableScroll().

Answer (score 4):

Adding this option to the `config.xml` did the trick for me.

```
<preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="true" />
```

It has been removed in [Cordova 3.2.0](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/RELEASENOTES.md#320-20131120) but is available in [cordova-plugin-keyboard](https://github.com/cjpearson/cordova-plugin-keyboard#cordovapluginskeyboardshrinkview).

You need to install this plugin and this option will work again

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-keyboard
```

Comment: Mine was resolved by installing the cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard plugin. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

make sure of this in your config.xml

```
<preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="true" />
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it solves the problem the correct way

Comment: Is there a modern day equivalent of this option? It seems to not exist anymore.

Comment: this is removed as of cordova 8x