# android keyboard displaces the ion-content by pushing it up

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Trying to solve this issue for the past couple days with no avail.

I tried a number of different suggestions:
[How to prevent keyboard push up webview at iOS app using phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820088/how-to-prevent-keyboard-push-up-webview-at-ios-app-using-phonegap)

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ios-keyboard-push-content-out-of-view/6715/last

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/5432

But none of them seem to work, or at least don't address my problem.

I've implemented an "ionic elastic chat" feature in my app:
https://codepen.io/rossmartin/pen/XJmpQr

however, when I focus on the input textarea, the keyboard doesn't cover the ion-content, but it displaces it by, it seems, the height of the keyboard.

[image]
Test message, which I had to "blindly" enter and press the hardware back button for the keyboard to disappear, and go back to normal.

This problem also happens on another screen, however it occurs ONCE the first time I focus on my search bar, but every other subsequent time it's normal.

[image]
As you can see here it pushes it up and you can see where the cursor is.

My app.jssettings

```
        ionic.Platform.isFullScreen = true;
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
        }
```

and I tried additional setup:

```
    window.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow', keyboardShowHandler);

    function keyboardShowHandler(e){
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);
        }, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I managed to fix this, just after I posted this question:

For anybody else that may be having this issue, what worked for me was:

In the AndroidManifest.xml file (located in platforms\android directory), change the  attribute to:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

<activity 
  ...
  ...
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
...
</activity>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! After hours of searching, this solved my problem :)

Comment: I'm guessing something has changed because AndroidManifest.xml is no longer in platforms\android.