# Prevent page/view push-up when keyboard opens in iOS

Tags: ios, browser

I am working on a form having a fixed header(for action buttons) and have encountered different behavior in iOS(both Safari and Chrome). The problem is that the OS is pushing entire web-view up whenever the keyboard opens, hiding the header which should be always visible.

Tried few solutions [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Awup.gif)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619762/how-to-prevent-ios-keyboard-from-pushing-the-view-off-screen-with-css-or-js/55630611#answer-38621037), [[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHrKh.gif)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820088/how-to-prevent-keyboard-push-up-webview-at-ios-app-using-phonegap)(the JavaScript/jQuery part) and few other similar options. None of them solve this properly. I can't use native/hybrid support as mentioned [here](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/prevent-ios-keyboard-push-up).

Below is what I have tried -

**Default behavior -** The view scrolls up, hiding the header

[image]

**After scroll override -** The UI jumps on every click on input/textarea and header also hides sometimes.

[image]

```
// tried code to override iOS push behaviour
$("body").on("focus", "input, textarea", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation(); // this can be ignored
  let winScroll = window.scrollY;
  window.scrollTo({
    top: winScroll
  });
});
```

Is there any way to keep the header always visible and fixed at top and rest of view may scroll, just like in browsers(not iOS)? [Code to replicate this behaviour](https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-flower-sxjob) with [full-page view](https://sxjob.codesandbox.io/).

Comment: Did you make it work?

Comment: @MadhavanSundararaj, I haven't got a solution for my case(JavaScript only, can't change CSS).
But [CSS Flex solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069734/fixed-header-footer-with-scrollable-content#answer-21168136) approach works properly.