# Ionic show keyboard issue - gray bar on top

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

We have an application with the following behavior when the keyboard is opened on iOS (it does not happen on Android):

[image]

We tried to let the screen content aligned to the top with `padding-top: 0px` but this "flicker" still happens. Only difference is that when aligned to the top the gray bar is smaller.

If we disable the scroll with `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);` the issue does not happen but the screen does not scroll so the touched field stay hidden behind the keyboard. Does anyone got this issue and managed to solve it?

```
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.17
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.13 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v7.5.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002
```

Answer (score 0):

Open config.xml and add this:

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
```

if aren't there

Comment: Nguyễn, unfortunately they already are in my config.xml with the same values.

Comment: ok then just follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820088/how-to-prevent-keyboard-push-up-webview-at-ios-app-using-phonegap

Comment: I tried the `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` without success. Curiously when I put a breakpoint in any line of the function created to store both calls the gray bar does not appear. Even tried with `scrollTop` but same result.

Comment: try this, final thing cross my mind cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped this in my question. `disableScroll(true)` prevents this behavior but the field stay hidden behind the keyboard as said in the question.